# How do I pass parameters throught ifram in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application in `ASP.Net` and I am implementing a `Network Graph Library`.
The `Network Graph` is located on a page called `Test.aspx`.
I am calling `Test.aspx` through `iframe`:

```
 DetailsBody.Text = DetailsBody.Text + "<td><iframe scrolling=\"no\" 
 id=\"graphframe\" src=\"Test.aspx\" width=\"100%\" 
 height=\"275px\"></iframe></td>";
```

I need to pass a parameter from the page where the `iframe` is located to the `Test.aspx` page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass the param like this.

```
<iframe src="Test.aspx?YourParam=<%=somevariable%>" scrolling=\"no\" width="100" height="275px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and for multipal param:

```
<iframe src="Test.aspx?Param1=<%=somevariable%>&Param2=<%=vartwo%>&Param3=<%=varthree%>" scrolling=\"no\" width="100" height="275px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Okay and how do I access Param1 for example in Test.aspx page?

Comment: Request.QueryString["YourParam"]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401651/how-to-access-parameters-sent-from-iframe-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following approach:

1. **Session** - provided that the pages are on a single web application.
2. **Query strings** - dynamically append query string when defining the **iframe src** attribute.

Comment: Can you give me an example on the second solution? Note that I need to pass many parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Pass the parameters through the Code behind,

```
 HtmlControl frame1 = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("I_Frame_Name");
        frame1.Attributes["src"] = "Test.aspx";
        frame1.Attributes["scrolling"] = "no";
        frame1.Attributes["id"] = "graphframe";
        frame1.Attributes["width"] = "100%";
        frame1.Attributes["height"] = "275px";
```