# How to access parameters sent from iframe in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application project in `ASP.Net` and I have two separate pages:
In the first page `Default.aspx`, I am using the `iframe` to call the second page `Test.aspx`.
I passed two parameters in the `src` attribute of `iframe`.

```
<iframe src="Test.aspx?Param1=<%=var1%>&Param2=<%=var2%>" 
scrolling=\"no\" width="100" height="275px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The question is how to access `Param`1 or `Param2` in the `Test.aspx` page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Access where? when? Those params are sent from default to test, so default should have them already.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is (or what type of code you are looking for) - your Default.aspx already have these 2 parameter - you can render them where you want as many times as you want, not just in src attribute...

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. The question is how to access Param1 an Param2 in the Test.aspx page.

Comment: Hey guy, that's not very well idea to learn ASP.NET by forum questions. Did you considered to read some book about ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be available as `Param1` and `Param2` in the [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property of the request in Test.aspx, in the form `Request.QueryString["Param1"]` and must already be present as `var1` and `var2` in the parent Default.aspx

Comment: +1. For answer for both pages. I've missed the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400994/how-do-i-pass-parameters-throught-ifram-in-asp-net) where it is clear that this question is about "how to get query params on Test.aspx" :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am searching for. Thank you